# How to connect a Yamaha PSR 60 to a HI FI speaker system

Tags: digital-piano

How do I connect a Yamaha PSR 60 portable keyboard to a HI FI speaker system?

Comment: This cannot be connected directly to a *speaker system*. Any outlets will need connecting to an *amplifier* then to speakers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a manual for this keyboard available at http://www.synthmanuals.com/manuals/yamaha/psr-60/owners_manual/psr60e.pdf. This is the relevant page (pg 23); you can see that you can use an RCA cable (the one with red and white ends on it) to connect to a stereo system.

[image]